# Detuning multiple voice synth bass - good or bad idea

Tags: mixing, bass, sub-bass

Some people use and recommend **creating sub basses with multiple voices** (detuned and sightly panned). They are aiming for a fatter voice (it definitely becomes fatter).

Also other people elsewhere say that it is the **best to keep the lowest voices as simple as possible**, like highpassing the original bass if needed and putting a pure sine or triangle below. (*Excellent article here: [Mixing bass](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/sep12/articles/mixing-bass.htm)*)

The former (multiple voice) approach sounds great when the stuff played alone. (Un)fortunately mixes rarely contain one instrument :).

### Questions

- What is the approach that results in fat, warm bass, but clear, defined and also "safe" on different PAs and sound systems?
- What's your experience with the multiple voice basses working in mix?
- Is there a gain in mixing bass frequencies to mono if the recording is not considered for vinyl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:
fat = a strong fundamental frequencies
warm = a good amount one present low mid/bass frequencies 100- 300 Hz also detuned sometimes
defined = a clean sub bass and some higher mids to give the bass some presence

What you want is to take a bass and make it sound deep and warm. you can detune if you want, but what is more important -> make good use of the synths lowpass filter. Analogue filters have a warmer feel so you could try that. Then remove the lowest frequency with a high pass. automate the cut-off frequency to remove the fundamental on every note played.

Also try to saturate the bass to get some more frequencies into the bass sound -> more warmth

To the stereo thingy why sub bass should always stay mono:
We can't locate bass/we can't hear bass below c.a. 80 hz. We only feel those frequencies. So there is no use in panning the stuff around. 
If you want a stereo bass then try to build one that is mono to at least 100-200 hz and then spread it. you need to layer some synths to do this in most cases or use modulation fx like choruses with a high pass.
Another reason why bass should be mono is because of mono compatibility. Stereo bass might collapse when you put it in mono like a lot of club PAs -> your track sounds weak.

But never forget the rule: what sounds right is right, but always check in mono!

Question 2: 
Multiple voice bass is a good attempt is you use the different layers intelligently like 1 synth for sub bass, another sub bass one octave above then 1 saw bass patch filtert down and high passed then 1 subbbass that you distort 1 stereo detuned filter saw bass, one chorused/fxed sawbass one patch with a lot of transients, one white noise plug in and so on and so on. But really you make mixing and especially mastering a lot easier if you just use a mono sub sine wave since everything else might collapse or you can't hear it and i takes energy

Question 3:
 There is no gain if you keep it mono. If it is stereo there might be a gain change if you mono it.

peace

Comment: So, basically you say that below 100 Hz there should be only one :), and that's one voice (and maybe its upper octave for audibility), then above 100 Hz, all dirty tricks can be considered (if it is highpassed, of course).

Comment: yeah roughly you need to experiment for the different sounds and genera where to go stereo. for house music everything is mono up to 250-300 hz in a lot of songs. the highs on the other hand are really spread out to the extreme and the mids are clever crafted in most good songs.